# How to Upload Image to AWS server from rails Controller

Tags: mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3.1, mongoid, paperclip, aws-sdk

Please Help for Upload image on AWS server in Controller.

I want following things to do.
  1. Submit form data with image.
  2. Get the image in controller and upload to AWS server.
  3. No model coding for upload image to AWS.

Instead of write code in model as below

`has_mongoid_attached_file :avatar, {
      path: ':class/:id/:style/:basename.:extension',
      storage: :s3,
      bucket: bucket_name,
      s3_credentials: {
          access_key_id: 'access_key_id',
          secret_access_key: 'secret_access_key'
      },
      styles: {
          thumb: ['90x90^', :jpg],
          feature: ['220x142^', :jpg],
          show_page: ['720x420^', :jpg],
          preview: ['145x90^', :jpg]
      }
  }`

I want to upload image directly from controller.

and only save the URL of uploaded image in database instead of below.

`"attachment_file_name": "imagename.png",
  "attachment_content_type": "image/png",
  "attachment_file_size": 1235,
  "attachment_updated_at": TimeStamp,`

i want to store only URL like this
`avatar = https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket_name/imagename.png`

NOTE: My project in `Rails 3.1.12` , `Ruby 1.9.3p484` using `mongoid`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass url option in model , like this

```
 has_mongoid_attached_file :avatar, {
        :url            => ':s3_alias_url',
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi friend your store S3 credential model this is wrong thing, you need to store s3 credential in separate yml file.

In Your config/production.rb

```
# config/environments/production.rb
     config.paperclip_defaults = {
       :storage => :s3,
       :s3_credentials => {
       :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
       :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
       :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
      } 
     }
```

Writer your paperclip.rb

```
  config/initializers/paperclip.rb
  Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = ':s3_domain_url'
  Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path]= '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename'
```

In your model need to validate image type

```
  has_attached_file :avatar, styles: {
     thumb: '100x100>',
     square: '200x200#',
     medium: '300x300>'
  }

 # Validate the attached image is image/jpg, image/png, etc
 validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
```